# DOS in HSE06 - KPOINTS

Tags: vasp, density-of-states, hse06

To calculate DOS using HSE06, is it necessary to use a denser KPOINTS?

PS: steps: preconverge PBE --> HSE06 (Damped, LSUBROT=true, ISMEAR=-5)

Comment: Yes you will need, please refer to a similar question https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9882/1554.